# Aspx page working in background even after browser window is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an aspx website which is hosted in an IIS server. The website allows user to search for some information and user can export the details to excel. Once the export is successful an email is sent to the user with a link to the excel. Recently I observed that even if the web browser is closed within few seconds of clicking export button report is generated and mail is sent. I am actually very happy to see this behaviour but can anyone tell the actual reason behind this?

Comment: How are you "exporting to Excel"? Are you using COM Interop? PIAS?

Comment: RDLC is used for the export and COM Interop is used to rename the excel sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user clicks the export button the request is sent to the server and the server will process that request until it ends, in your case in an email.

Even if the client browser closed after the button was pressed the request was still sent and the server has no idea that the client browser closed.

Now, normally (with the browser open throughout the process) the request gets sent and the **client waits for the response** which returns at the end of the processing. This makes sense when your getting a back a page that tells you what has happened but when your action creates other side effects (emails for example) it may not seem that logical to have the client wait. In which case, consider using an ajax request to send the request which will ensure the rest of the page can still be interacted with whilst the request is being processed.

Comment: Does this have any drawbacks on server performance? And how is it different from Asynchronous processing in this case?

Comment: Asynchronous processing will use the standard request/response pattern and therefore utilise the same resources but the browser wont wait on a response before you can do anything else with the page. Basically the work has to be done either way but the ajax/async route will provide a better user experience (no waiting for a new page). Crucially though, in both cases once the request is sent the server will continue to process the code until the end (or an exception)

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't upvote as I don't have enough reputation. Marking this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your're using Office Interop or PIAS's, that's your problem man!

See this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

There are many other choices and no need to use an unsupported technology for the server side.